# How to set LinearVelocity exactly in onSceneTouchEvent?

Tags: box2d, vector, andengine, scene

I'm beginner in Android programming.
And i use AndEngine GLS2 with Body and AnimatedSprite.

I have a object ball and i want to move it to follow my hand. This is description for my idea:
[image: Vector]

And my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene,
            final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
     ballObject.getBodyball().setLinearVelocity(
                    new Vector2(pX, pY));
}
```

How to get exactly variables:`pX`, `pY` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple math. First you find the vector between those two points. Then create a vector (use vector pool) from it. Let's say your touch coordinates are [p1x, p1y] and the up coordinates are [p2x, p2y]:

```
dx = p2x - p1x;
dy = p2y - p1y;

Vector2 v = Vector2Pool.obtain(dx, dy);
```

You can normalize it to get the same speed everytime. Simply call:

```
v.nor();
```

Then you can set desired speed by:

```
v.mul(scalar);
```

Where scalar is a constant to make it go faster or slower. See the [Vector2 class](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/blob/GLES2/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java) for more.

Comment: How to set speed limit for ball object? It seems to run very fast. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer.